# NodeJS and Socket.io on Mobile, can I poll every second?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

How lightweight is Socket.io? Would I be able to emit a message from my client to my server every second without problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.io works using a stack of available IO mechanisms. First, it tries HTML5 web sockets. These essentially create a proper TCP socket, so there's very little overhead. As long as this is available, a mobile application should be fine.

However, the lower mechanisms on the stack involve Flash objects and polling with `XmlHttpRequest`, the latter of which can be very wasteful when using a mobile application. I certainly wouldn't suggest using a 1 second polling rate on a phone.

My suggestion would be to detect when socket.io reverts to polling mode and alter the way your app works. Use a low-ish polling rate, but force update on demand when necessary.

Comment: When it's on the fallbacks how well does it detect when a user is disconnected? Is it just when it tries to do it's heartbeat that it realizes that the user isn't there anymore?

Comment: Not sure. You'd have to check the documentation.